# Составить регулярное выражение для языка c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, нужно распознавать строки вида /abc/q<число>/zxc.
При этом в паттерне меняется только <число>, строка должна начинаться на этот паттерн и не иметь продолжения, т.е. abc и zxc - фиксированные.

Comment: `^abc/q[0-9]+/zxc$`

Comment: а еще вопрос, если на конце может быть zxc или vbn, при этом только одно из них и только один раз?

Comment: `^abc/q[0-9]+/(zxc|vbn)$` попробуйте так

Comment: А экранировать / разве не надо?

Comment: Нет, прямой слеш в регулярках не является спецсимволом

Answer (score 0):

Общий ответ

```
^\/abc\/q\d+\/zxc$
```